# Problem with saving all results of loop to Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a loop like below, and by doing so I need to calculate a prediction for store = 1 and store = 85, but nevermind... the real problem is, why in results data frame: "df_all_2" I have results only for store 1, so my loop works badly because I need results for store 85 and 1, but I do not see the error in this loop, can you help me?

```
sample_df = data.query('Store in [85, 1]')
Store_list = sample_df["Store"].unique().tolist()

df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"])
df_result.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

for store in Store_list:
    sample_df = data_XGB[data_XGB["Store"]==store]

    ......
    
    test_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_test_XGB)
    train_set['Sales_Prediction'] = reg.predict(X_train_XGB)
    
    df_all = pd.concat([test_set, train_set], sort=True)
    df_all = df_all[["Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"]]
    df_all.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df_all["Date"] = df_all["Date"].astype("datetime64")
    df_all.sort_values(by="Date", inplace=True)
    df_all.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
    
df_all_2 = pd.concat([df_result, df_all], sort=False)
```

[image]

I try for example to write: `df_result = df_result.combine_first(df_all)`instead of last like df_all_2 but when I use your code with indentation I have results only for 85 and without indentation, I have results only for 1, but I need to have both 1 and 85.

I assume that I overwrite my loop but I do not know how?

Answer (score 0):

Try using apply

```
def sales_pred(store):
    if store == 1 or store ==85:
       # do your sales prediction logic here

    return #prediction

df_result.loc[:, 'sales_prediction'] = df1.apply(lambda x: matches_lookup(x['store'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have

```py
df_all_2 = pd.concat([df_result, df_all], sort=False)
```

after the loop and not inside, so it works only once. Please try doing something like:

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Store", "Sales", "Sales_Prediction"])
df_result.set_index("Date", inplace=True)

for store in Store_list:
    sample_df = data_XGB[data_XGB["Store"]==store]

    ......
# I have skipped your data transformationlines except the last one
    df_all.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
# here you use tab (or four spaces) and replace df_all_2 with df_result
    df_result= pd.concat([df_result, df_all], sort=False)

df_result
```